# Force hibernate (deep sleep) in OSX 10.8(.2)

Tags: sleep-wake, power, hibernate, power-nap

How can you force the computer (in this case a laptop [rMBP]) into the "hibernate" state where it writes the RAM to the HDD/SSD so that the battery can last for the advertised 30 days.

I know that this can be achieved by waiting 70 minutes (4200 secs) after it is in sleep mode (if you haven't adjusted the default time settings), but is there a way to force it into this state?

I am having wake problems, and want to test this state of waking from.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it's equivalent to the deep sleep mode, but `sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 25` makes computers hibernate immediately when going to sleep.

> hibernatemode = 3 (binary 0011) by default on supported portables. The system will store a copy of memory to persistent storage (the disk), and will power memory during sleep. The system will wake from memory, unless a power loss forces it to restore from disk image.
>
> hibernatemode = 25 (binary 0001 1001) is only settable via pmset. The system will store a copy of memory to persistent storage (the disk), and will remove power to memory. The system will restore from disk image. If you want "hibernation" - slower sleeps, slower wakes, and better battery life, you should use this setting.